# cookie & session is not getting destroy when executing code on live server?

Tags: php, session, cookies

On localhost, cookie is getting destroy perfectly but when i am executing it on live server, cookie is getting created but not getting destroy and session is also not getting destroy.

Here is the code of destroying both session and cookie:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['userid']))
{
setcookie('user','',time()-4800,'/','liveserverdomain');
session_destroy();  
header('location: http://www.liveserverdomain/login.php');
}
```

Please suggest to me a solution of destroying the session and cookie.

Comment: From the manual, next to using session_destroy: `In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.` So it seems you still need to unset the session variables

Answer (score 0):

You should check the timezone of the server and match it to your localhost. You have a time-window of 4800 seconds? Try raising the value to 86400 (a day).

**edit:** And by the way , are you sure the cookie you want to delete is named `'user'` ? ... shouldn't it be `session_name()` ?

Deleting the cookie only 'clears' the session at client side and isn't safe enough. You also need to clear it on server side.

And look at my comment to your question. You need to unset the Session variables `$_SESSION = array();`

Comment: is your question answered?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use unset() like this:

```
unset($_COOKIE["mycookie"]);
```